# How to resolve this SQLiteException: no such column ?

Tags: android, sqlite

The entries are getting submitted successfully but when pressing the "view" button, the application crashes and Logcat output is:

> D/Error(2808): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: names: , while compiling: SELECT id, names, items, quantity, price FROM orderDetails

How do I resolve this?

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "orders";
private static final String TABLE_ORDERS = "orderDetails";

// Now, column names

private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "names";
private static final String KEY_ITEM = "items";
private static final String KEY_QUANTITY = "quantity";
private static final String KEY_PRICE = "price";

private DatabaseHandler handler;
private final Context myContext;
private SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    myContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ORDERS + "(" + KEY_ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_ITEM + " BLOB, "
            + KEY_QUANTITY + " REAL, " + KEY_PRICE + " REAL);";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ORDERS);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void addEntry(String name, String item, float quantity, float price) {
    try {
        handler = new DatabaseHandler(myContext);
        myDatabase = handler.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        cv.put(KEY_ITEM, item);
        cv.put(KEY_QUANTITY, quantity);
        cv.put(KEY_PRICE, price);

        myDatabase.insert(TABLE_ORDERS, null, cv);
        handler.close();

        // delete this toast
        Toast.makeText(myContext, "It worked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        Toast.makeText(myContext, "It failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("Error", e.toString());
    }

}

public String getEntries() {

    try {
        handler = new DatabaseHandler(myContext);
        myDatabase = handler.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_ITEM,
                KEY_QUANTITY, KEY_PRICE };

        Cursor c = myDatabase.query(TABLE_ORDERS, columns, null, null, null,
                null, null);
        String result = "";

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            result = result + c.getString(0) + " |" + c.getString(1) + " |"
                    + c.getString(2) + " |" + c.getString(3) + " |"
                    + c.getString(4) + "\n";
        }
        handler.close();
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Error", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

**[1]  First of all delete the created database from** your AVD or Real Device, because the table already created there has not column KEY_NAME("names")

**[2]  Then next time** when will you run app the table will created with following code in table::

```
String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ORDERS + "(" + KEY_ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_ITEM + " BLOB, "
            + KEY_NAME + " TEXT, "  //  ADD THIS  COLUMN
            + KEY_QUANTITY + " REAL, " + KEY_PRICE + " REAL);";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
```

---

You have **forgotten to put KEY_NAME** in creation query of table see following is your code:

```
String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ORDERS + "(" + KEY_ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_ITEM + " BLOB, "
            + KEY_QUANTITY + " REAL, " + KEY_PRICE + " REAL);";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
```

Comment: Hey, frend **MUST follow** my First Solution about **DELETING OLDER** created database.

Comment: Otherwise **OLDER DATABASE** will not have "names" column. So, for creatind new table having "names" column, you have to **DELETE or ALTER Older Database**.

Comment: Yes it worked, thanks a ton :) Yes I had to delete older table.

Answer (score 0):

Well as you see, you don't have the column names in your table definition:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ORDERS + "(" + KEY_ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_ITEM + " BLOB, "
            + KEY_QUANTITY + " REAL, " + KEY_PRICE + " REAL);";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

}
```

Comment: No problem, pal.  We all have times like that. :)

Answer (score -1):

Is "names" a reserved word. try using [names] with square brackets.